# How can I raise the bowl water level in a low-usage toilet?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I just installed this low water usage toilet. It’s a single flush model. It’s working fine but the bowl water level is low. It has an R&T fill valve with a red ring which doesn’t seem to do much to the tank’s water level when rotated. There’s no visible adjustment screw either. Of course my fill valve is different than the one shown in the instructions.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] to add a picture. There are some typical installation mistakes that would then be obvious, such as not putting the refill tube into the overflow pipe.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, for two reasons:

- Obviously having more water in the bowl would make it... use more water, which it was specifically designed to not do.
- The level is determined by the weir of the outlet trap formed into the porcelain and isn't adjustable. The fill valve controls the level in the *tank* only.